# jquery margin won't adapt on first click

Tags: jquery, css, function, event-handling, show

If you click on an element with class "clickable", a div "display" will appear.
The height of the "display" divs are not equal.
Depending on the height of this div, the top-margin of another div "container" should adapt.
However, this works on the first click, but not for consecutive clicks: from the second "clickable" on there are always two clicks necessary: the first click will load the content, the second click will adapt the top-margin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var display = $("#display");
var clickable = $(".clickable");
display.hide();

clickable.click(function(){
    var clickableid = clickable.attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'get',
        url: 'process.php?id=' + clickableid,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(content) {
            $('#display').load('process.php?id=' + clickableid);
            display.show(function(){
                var newmargin = $("#display").height();
                $('#container').css({"margin-top": + newmargin});
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of:

```
    display.show(function(){
        var newmargin = $("#display").height();
        $('#container').css({"margin-top": + newmargin});
    });
```

I also tried:

```
    display.show()
    var newmargin = $("#display").height();
    $('#container').css({"margin-top": + newmargin};
```

Unfortunately to no avail: only the way of showing up was different.
Anyone having an idea?

Comment: what do you mean by showing up differed? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @C-link I corrected it: without the function the div appears immediately, using show(function) etc. there more of an animation.

Comment: I ended up with this code: `$(document).ready(function(){
 var display = $("#display");
 var clickable = $(".clickable");
 display.hide();
 
 clickable.click(function(){
  display.hide();
  var clickableid = clickable.attr('id');
  $('#display').load('process.php?id=' + clickableid);
  display.show(function() {
   var newmargin = $("#display").height();
   $('#container').css({"margin-top": newmargin});
  });
 });` Apparently I needed to reinitialize the "display" div by hiding it in the first place. Now the top-margin of the "container" div below adapts in only one click.

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment so I have to offer an answer which really isn't, but I think you want to check out `.done(function( data ){...})` Success doesn't necessarily mean the DOM is done rendering the results of the get.

> These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when the $.ajax() request terminates. This allows you to assign multiple callbacks on a single request, and even to assign callbacks after the request may have completed. (If the request is already complete, the callback is fired immediately.)

Also, I'm confused by the second request made in calling `.load()` which is a synchronous way of doing exactly what the `$.ajax` request is doing (??)

[JQuery .ajax() docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write the css() method would be without the plus-sign, like so: `$('#container').css({"margin-top": newmargin};`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Saxeen. There is however no effect on the execution.